# What is a "node project"?

Tags: node.js

What is a "NodeJs project"? How would you describe a node project to a person that is moving to learn nodeJs? Or, at a job interview, for example, if someone  asked you this question, how would you reply? How would you describe a "node project"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A node project is any program that is built to run on the node.js Javascript engine and use its built-in runtime library.  It could be a simple one file script to carry out some sort of local scripting operation or it could be whole directory hierarchy of script files and installed modules designed to be a clustered server running a website at scale or anything in between.

node.js itself is a very flexible development environment that can be used to create a wide variety of programs.  It's somewhat analogous to Python (though obviously a different language) in that it comes with a language interpreter, a runtime library of built-in functionality and a community of modules (most of which are open source) that you can add in to your project.

If you're hoping to seem node.js-proficient in an interview and don't even know the answer to this already, then you have a lot of additional studying to do because a few simple followup questions about the relevant strengths of node.js compared to other environments or a few quick programming questions about the node.js environment would likely quickly show the limitations of your knowledge.